# Next.js Fast Refresh custom animation

Tags: next.js

The Fast Refresh / Hot Reloading in Next.js comes with a small triangle animation in the lower right corner by default:

[image: reload animation]

Is there any way to customise this? I'd like the whole page to turn grey or similar so I get a visual feedback that my file change is actually taking effect and that I didn't happen to change the wrong file or something,.

Answer (score 0):

A very ugly workaround until someone with better next.js knowledge helps out:

```
// Put this in your _app.js file
if (global.window) {
  global.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    const watcher = window.document.getElementById('__next-build-watcher')
    if (watcher) {
        const newStyle = global.document.createElement('style')
        newStyle.innerHTML = '#icon-wrapper { width: 100vw!important; height: 100vh!important; opacity: 0.3!important; } #container { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)!important; }'
        watcher.shadowRoot.appendChild(newStyle)
    }
  });
}
```

Makes that triangle icon `100vw 100vh` and semi-transparent instead of  `16px 16px` .